# When should I use an Optional String in my model?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

In my model code currently in some places, I am doing

```
var optionalString : String?
```

and in some places

```
var otherString : String = ""
```

When it is an optional and I am unwrapping it, I am scared it shouldn't be nil and just for being on the safe side I do

```
let newString = optionalString ?? ""
```

With optionals, I need to unwrap and perform nil checks. It makes the code a little less readable.

Should a String ever be an optional in the model? Any scenario where it must be one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, String optionals and empty strings are interchangable sometimes.

Let's say we have a person class, it has a `name` property. In this case, a person *must* have a name, so optional and empty strings are interchangable (You can use either). You can use `nil` or `""` to indicate that a person has no name. They mean the same. You can declare a constant too:

```
let NoName = ""
```

And you can just check it with this very abstract constant, rather than `nil`, which is a little bit less abstract.

On the other hand, sometimes you must use an optional. And that is when `nil` and `""` have different meanings in the context. Let's use our person class to illustrate this as well. The person class has a property called `dogName`. If he/she does not have a dog, it is `nil`. If he/she has a dog but has not given it a name, it is an empty string. And if he/she has a dog and has given it a name, it would be `"fido"` or some other names. In this case, `nil` means he/she has no dog, and `""` means his/her dog has no name. They have *different* meanings!

**Conclusion: When nil and empty string have the same meaning, use optional optionally. When nil and empty string have different meanings, use optional.**

Comment: Thanks the dog example made sense. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that tick! @runios

Comment: Yes it does. While I feel Nikolai's example is closer to programming. I tick yours as you gave it first.

Answer (score 2):

Optionals are used when the absence of a value (the string) has differing semantics from an empty value.

**Simple example:**

A password could be either

- set to some string
- empty
- not yet set at all.

Here, the "not-set" case must be handled differently than the "empty" case.

You should only use optionals when model logic differs for empty vs. missing string. Same is true for collection types (Array, Dictionary).

Comment: Awesome! great example.